# Text PDF to Excel in VBA

Tags: excel, pdf

I have used the code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48028418/copy-and-paste-whole-story-from-word-to-excel) and tried to extract a PDF file. The code extracts the PDF perfectly in Excel, but I keep getting notification messages. I've disable Display Alerts, but it does not make a difference.

```
Sub ImportPDF()
    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Dim wdFileName

    Set objWord = CreateObject("word.Application")
    wdFileName = "C:\42046_120_2077802.pdf"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set objDoc = GetObject(wdFileName)

    objWord.Documents.Open (wdFileName)
    objWord.Selection.WholeStory
    objWord.Selection.Copy

    Sheets(1).Select
    [A1].Select
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Paste

    'objDoc.Close ' I get an error message if I add this (Object does not support this property or method)
    objWord.Quit
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

The messages I get are the following:

[image: File In use message]

[image: Word message convert to PDF]

[image: Word message file in use]

Is there a way to get rid of the messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
Sub ImportPDF()
    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Dim wdFileName

    Set objWord = CreateObject("word.Application")
    wdFileName = "C:\42046_120_2077802.pdf"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(wdFileName)
    objWord.Selection.WholeStory
    objWord.Selection.Copy

    Sheets(1).Select
    [A1].Select
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Paste

    objDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    objWord.Quit
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This still will not suppress the _Word_ alerts

Comment: Thanks, that works. I still get the 'Word will not convert..." but clicking the 'don't show this message again' once gets rid of this message

Comment: @Selrac - look up the additional parameters of [`Documents.Open`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.documents.open), especially  - **ConfirmConversions** - *"True to display the Convert File dialog box if the file isn't in Microsoft Word format"*, so it should be `False`. `Application.DisplayAlerts` refers to the Excel application, not the instance of Word.

Comment: This still shows the warning 'Word will not convert..."

Answer (score 1):

`Application.DisplayAlerts` refers to the *Excel* application, **not** the instance of *Word*, which is displaying the alerts.

To avoid the first two alerts, use the additional parameters of [`Documents.Open`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.documents.open)

- **ConfirmConversions** - *"True to display the Convert File dialog box if the file isn't in Microsoft Word format"* - so `False`.
- **ReadOnly** - *"True to open the document as read-only"* - so `True`.

Closing the document without saving changes *seems* to also avoid the third pop-up. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32736915/how-to-clear-office-clipboard-with-vba) might be an option as well.

```
Sub ImportPDF()
    Dim objWord As Object, objDoc As Object
    Dim wdFileName As String

    Set objWord = CreateObject("word.Application")
    wdFileName = "C:\42046_120_2077802.pdf"

    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(wdFileName, False, True)
    objWord.Selection.WholeStory
    objWord.Selection.Copy

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Select
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Paste

    objDoc.Close False
    objWord.Quit
End Sub
```